# Limit for divisibilty of integers in Python

Tags: python, integer-division, floor

```
import math

n, k = map(int, input().split())

print('NO' if (math.floor(n/k) % 2 == 0) else 'YES')
```

The above code takes 2 integers n and k as input and tries to tell if [image: floor of n/k] is odd or even.

Now the test cases :

1. **Input**: n = 10 and k = 3    **Output**: YES   **Verdict**: Correct.
2. **Input**: n = 1000 and k = 3    **Output**: YES   **Verdict**: Correct.
3. **Input**: n = 10000000000000000 and k = 3    **Output**: YES   **Verdict**: Correct.
4. **Input**: n = 100000000000000000 and k = 3    **Output**: NO   **Verdict**: Wrong.
5. **Input**: n = 1000000000000000000 and k = 3    **Output**: NO   **Verdict**: Wrong.

Now, what I found is that for n < 10e16 it works fine but for n = 10e17, 10e18, etc. it gives the wrong answer. I am not able to find an explanation for this behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Happy coding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)  (The linked answer explains things in terms of very small numbers, but the same problem applies to very large numbers.)

Comment: Integers in Python have unlimited precision, but the division produces a `float` which does not.

Comment: Did you try to print `math.floor(n/k)`?  That should answer your question immediately.

Comment: @0x5453 Now I know how floating points are implemented, but still doesn't solve my problem. Still, how do I obtain the correct output?

Comment: @MarkRansom It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Use integer division `//` so you don't encounter floating point precision limits.  I.e. `n//k` instead of `math.floor(n/k)`.